# rxjs observable doesn't subscribe with async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, async-pipe

I have the following pipeline and html template, but the app always displays `#noMatch` and doesn't logs `"in the pipe"` in the `reduce` function. I feel it's a matter of timing but I'm not able to fix it.

**ts**

```
user$: Observable<User> = new Observable<User>();
matches$: Observable<User[]> = this.user$.pipe(
  switchMap((user: User) => {
    this.type= user.type;
    return of([user, user, user]);
  }),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
);
filteredMatches$: Observable<{ type1: User[]; type2: User[] }>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.user$ = this.authService.user$;

  this.filteredMatches$ = this.matches$.pipe(
    reduce((acc: any, curr: User[]) => {
      if (!acc.type1) acc.type1= [];
      if (!acc.type2) acc.type2= [];
      console.log('in the pipe');

      this.networkingService.decideType(this.type, curr.type)
        ? acc.type1.push(curr)
        : acc.type2.push(curr);
      return acc;
    }),
  );
}
```

**html**

```
<ng-template *ngIf="(filteredMatches$ | async) as matches; else noMatch">
  <app-child *ngFor="let user of matches.type1" [user]="user">
  <app-child *ngFor="let user of matches.type2" [user]="user">
</ng-template>

<ng-template #noMatch>
    <app-no-match></app-no-match>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Have you tried parens around the pipe? `(filteredMatches$ | async) as matches; else noMatch`? Also, does `this.networkingService.decideType` return a promise, or is it synchronous?

Comment: Yeah I tried with the parens, and `ithis.networkingService.decideType` s synchronous (but apparently the reduce function is not called because `console.log("in the pipe")` is not logged

Comment: I think the problem comes from `matches$` not firing or firing too soon. Try to add a `shareReplay(1)` after the distinctUntilChanged. This will make the last value emit on subscription.

Comment: @Salketer I tried it, but without any success.

Comment: Are you sure that your subscription isn't just returning a falsy value? The problem with async subscription in an ngIf is that you can't tell the difference between a null because your observable isn't defined and a null because the subscribed value is falsy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah found it. You do this:

```
user$: Observable<User> = new Observable<User>();
matches$: Observable<User[]> = this.user$.pipe(
  switchMap((user: User) => {
    this.type= user.type;
    return of([user, user, user]);
  }),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
);
```

`mathes$` listens to `user$` which is a new Observable.

Then, on ngInit you do this:

```
this.user$ = this.authService.user$;
```

You replace the value of user$ with the authService's user$. But mathes$ is still subscribed to the first Observable, which is not doing anything.

I suggest you replace

```
 user$: Observable<User> = new Observable<User>();
 //by
 user$: Observable<User> = this.authService.user$;
```

Or better yet, directly use the authService's user$ instead of creating a property for it.

EDIT: In my opinion, there is no reason to use the ngOnInit here, you could simply have the observable set at the beggining...

```
matches$: Observable<User[]> = this.authService.user$.pipe(
  switchMap((user: User) => {
    this.type= user.type;
    return of([user, user, user]);
  }),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
);
filteredMatches$: Observable<{ type1: User[]; type2: User[] }> = this.matches$.pipe(
    reduce((acc: any, curr: User[]) => {
      if (!acc.type1) acc.type1= [];
      if (!acc.type2) acc.type2= [];
      console.log('in the pipe');

      this.networkingService.decideType(this.type, curr.type)
        ? acc.type1.push(curr)
        : acc.type2.push(curr);
      return acc;
    }),
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! Apparently the problem is more complex because now I can see the `matches$` observable emits 3 users as expected, but the `console.log` in the `reduce` still doesn't work.

Comment: @IgorCantele the `reduce` doesn't work, because it mutates `acc` and returns the mutated object, hence they will look `===` in any kind of comparison "previous value vs next value". Probably a simple `return {...acc}` instead of `return acc` will solve that. But generally that is why it's better to work on immutable values, instead of mutating objects' properties, pushing to arrays etc.

Comment: @IgorCantele to be quite frank with you I didn't check the content of the reduce at all! I only challenged the reason why it wasn't firing up.

Comment: @Salketer I accepted your answer because it was able to figure out why reduce wasn't working (missing seed) and you addressed the real topic of the question. It was very informative as well, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

@Salketer's answer is correct - the reason and the solution. Further: if, for some reason or another, the source observable isn't available yet in the constructor (it depends on some inputs, for example), you could do something like this

```
user$: Observable<User> = new Subject<User>(); 
matches$: Observable<User[]> // no changes here

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.authService.user$.subscribe(this.users$);
```

(A `Subject` is both an observable and an observer).

Comment: That's a very good point, this is normaly what I do when dealing with input Observables